# Report snapshots monthly with the filters

Tags: reporting, dashboard, versioning, snapshot

I would like a month-end snapshot of each report so that if the new data is added the report can be seen again with the old data and able to compare them with filter also.

This is like freezing the data each month and then play around with this data in the report even though new data is updated in objects.

I have already used the report snapshot feature of salesforce but it actually stores the basic values in the object. I want to see the report as it is with its filters available, is there any way to accomplish that?